# Excel won't save files created with xlsxwriter

Tags: xlsxwriter

I have successfully created an xlsx file with xlsx writer.  I can open it in Excel.  But, if I modify and try to Save As the file (to my home directory), I get an error:

> You do not have permission to save files to this location.
>
> Make sure that you have write access for this location, or select a different location.

I am able to save other Excel files, created by Excel, to this location without a problem.

So, what is "different" about xlsx files created with xlsxwriter compared to those created by Excel?  I'm using MacOS Mojave and Office 2019 if that makes a difference.  Is there some weird security setting in MacOS Mojave that is mucking things up?

My workaround is to copy and paste the content into a new Excel file.  Excel is happy to save that file to my home directory.  But, this loses the row height settings and the frozen panes.

Answer (score 0):

> So, what is "different" about xlsx files created with xlsxwriter compared to those created by Excel?

There isn't any difference. XlsxWriter goes to great lengths to create files in exactly the same way as Excel (2007).

> I'm using MacOS Mojave and Office 2019 if that makes a difference. Is there some weird security setting in MacOS Mojave that is mucking things up?

I tested with MacOS Mojave and Office 2016 (I don't have 2019) and I was able to save to my home directory without issue. I even made the file read only with `chmod -w` and I didn't get the error message that you did, and I was able to save it once I changed the name.

Is there anything unusual about the permissions of the xlsx file compared to other file in your home directory?:

```
ls -l xlsxwrite_file.xlsx
ls -l ~/*.xlsx
```

Comment: I am seeing some strange behavior.  When I do the ls -l, most of the Excel files have a group of 'group1'.  However, when I save an Excel file with changes, the group changes to 'group2'.  But, that doesn't explain the behavior since I'm able to save most files with 'group1', but not those created with xlsxwriter (which also are 'group1').

Don't know if the groups have anything to do with the problem.  Other than the group, the permissions are identical.  Same user name and same rwx settings '-rw-r--r--@'.

Comment: Can you `cp` the xlsxwriter file to your $HOME directory? Also, if you create a CSV file, open it with Excel and then try to save it to your $HOME directory does that work? It may be better to raise this as a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues) so we can debug this outside of the comments.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  But, just as mysteriously as the problem appeared, it has disappeared.  I can now modify and save the files as expected.  Probably some obscure security setting in MacOS, if I had to place a bet...